# RevisionInformation or ChangeInformation on LineNumberChangeRulerColumn

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to show the author or the ChangeInformation on a LineNumberChangeRulerColumn.

```
Iterator<IVerticalRulerColumn> it =  ruler2.getDecoratorIterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  IVerticalRulerColumn c = it.next();
  if(c instanceof LineNumberChangeRulerColumn){
    LineNumberChangeRulerColumn lnc = (LineNumberChangeRulerColumn)c;
    lnc.showLineNumbers(false);
    lnc.setDisplayMode(true);
            lnc.setRevisionInformation(ri);
    lnc.showRevisionAuthor(true);
    System.out.println("ci"+lnc.isShowingChangeInformation());
    System.out.println("ri"+lnc.isShowingRevisionInformation());    
  }         
}
```

But where does the ri (RevisionInformation) come from?
I tried to create one without luck, since it does not allow me to create a Revision? Pls help. eac

```
visionInformation ri = new RevisionInformation();
Revision r = new Revision();
r.addRange(new LineRange(1,10));
ri.addRevision(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

@eactor, How you are getting Revision Details!
From your code, there is no source from where the Revision Details you are getting.

Hope below will Help you.

If you are using **[svnkit](http://svnkit.com/)**:
You can refer the documentation for [printing subversion repository tree](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_A_Subversion_Repository_Tree) as an example.

Or

You can refer to the Implementation in [BuiltInAnnotate](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/polarion/team/svn/ui/annotate/BuiltInAnnotate.java.html)

```
Map revisions = new HashMap();
String [][]lines = annotateOp.getAnnotatedLines();
RGB palette = SVNTeamPreferences.getAnnotateRGB(SVNTeamUIPlugin.instance().getPreferenceStore(), SVNTeamPreferences.ANNOTATE_RGB_BASE_NAME);
boolean useOneRGB = SVNTeamPreferences.getAnnotateBoolean(SVNTeamUIPlugin.instance().getPreferenceStore(), SVNTeamPreferences.ANNOTATE_USE_ONE_RGB_NAME);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    BuiltInAnnotateRevision revision = (BuiltInAnnotateRevision)revisions.get(lines[i][0]);
    if (revision == null) {
     revisions.put(lines[i][0], revision = new BuiltInAnnotateRevision(lines[i][0], lines[i][4], useOneRGB ? palette : CommitterColors.getDefault().getCommitterRGB(lines[i][5])));
      info.addRevision(revision);
      }
    revision.addLine(Integer.parseInt(lines[i][6]));
  }
```

Comment: My original attention was to kind of abuse the svn version feature, to annotate information to a specific line. Like here: http://mohsenvakilian.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/eclipse-quickdiff.jpg but i would like to  annotate kind of profiler information to every line.